# Are Skeletal Primitives and Convolution Surface present in Blender?

Tags: add-on

I'd like to use Convolution Surface in my work but I didn't see it proposed in Blender. I was wondering if there was any add-on for Blender doing any kind of Skeletal Primitives (such as mentioned in [this course](http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/zhx/GM/012/00-ism.pdf), page 77)? *If you know of a software (or even a lib) allowing to use Convolution Surface in 3D Graphics, I'm also interested.*

Comment: Not sure to understand, but if this partiallly helps, you can set for each bone a custom shape in pose mode...

Comment: Not quite, but thx. :) The big idea behind skeletal primitives (the very big idea) is to have a path of vertices, and to generate specific kind of metaballs from those vertices.

Comment: Blender has something similar, the [Skin Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/skin.html) (based on this [paper](http://www.math.zju.edu.cn/ligangliu/CAGD/Projects/BMesh/))

Comment: @zeffil Thanks a lot for this approach. Even if there is no blending between the joins of the skeleton, it is actually almost what I wanted. :) This approach rise an issue though: when resizing a region (e.g. to get a bigger skin), the distance between vertices changes too, and the tessellation become less flowly. In the original paper, the authors gave the size of the region prior to the "sweeping" and "stitching" operations, which avoided such artifacts.

Comment: @Supercourgette unfortunately that 's the extent of what Blender has to offer out of the box. I expect the future will hold a lot more kinds of implicit skinning, but demand would need to grow.